# Unable to delete songs from iTunes Match - they always come back

Tags: itunes, icloud, itunes-match

I'm so lost here. I imported an audio book from CD into my iTunes library. The genre was wrong on one of the 5 CDs ("Spoken & Audio") instead of "Audio Book". So I changed it.
iTunes Match did its job, uploaded the titles and messed everything up. I ended up with all the titles being duplicated, one per genre.
In the end I just wanted to get rid of the files. I deleted the titles from iTunes 11 and checked in Findes that they are gone for good. I was also ask if I wanted to delete the titles in iCloud too. I agreed.
Then iTunes Match updated itself and everything was back. I retried - same issue. The titles come back with an iCloud icon.

How the heck can I get rid of the titles and restart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a pain, but you want to toggle iTunes Match and delete them again.

In iTunes:

1. Click the Store menu and select "Turn Off iTunes Match"
2. Click the Store menu and select "Turn On iTunes Match"
3. Delete Songs

Comment: Doesn't work. They are gone, then I select "Update iTM" and they're all back. I have now updated to iTunes 11.1.1 (11) and will retry.

Comment: Your advice plus the update to 11.1.1 (11) of iTunes fixed it.